# How do I get a LAN server working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I want to play on a LAN server with my brother, but I can't get it to show up on his MultiPlayer menu.

I made the server by clicking "Open to LAN", we both play on the same router, but it still never doesn't show up.

I have tried getting rid of all of the mods on his computer and my computer, both of us are playing on the same version.

Comment: I checked the answers on that question those things don't work, it doesn't address my question, I don't know what else to try please help

Comment: also, just to say, it worked once when I tried to connect using the demo account! so the problem might be something wrong with my Minecraft account

Comment: Are you both using the same account?

Comment: [ignore this part it is just to have enough characters to post my message]no I am not

Answer (score -3):

you can't connect wireless and wires at the same time like I read before and I hope this helps because that was always my problem with my sister's laptop and my pc.